# Span text does not appear in element with innerHtml

Tags: html, angular, innerhtml

I want to have two elements: `<p>` with inner html and in same `<p>` element `<span>` tag with normal text.

```
 <p innerHtml="{{ someText | slice: 0:150 }}">
  <span>...Read more</span></p>
```

The problem is, that with innerHtmml tag "...Read more" span text is not appearing in the screen. How I can solve this problem?
Note: I need those two: innerHtml+span text to be in one line.

Comment: why not append the `span` to `someText` and then use it?

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention that it will need to have it's own css style class

Comment: Yes, you can do that in the `component.ts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your component, you can have something like this

component.ts

```
someText = '<h2>A header </h2><p>Text to slice</p>';

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor() {
     someText = someText.slice(0,150);
     someText += '<span class="span_class">...Read more </span>';
   }
}
```